# How to disable core dumps on Debian 8

Tags: systemd, server-crashes, debian-jessie

I pretend I've already tried everything out there, but my Debian 8 keeps creating core dumps when something crashes. It's happening about once or twice in a month. It's a production server for a few websites, with packaged Apache 2.4, php5-fpm and mysql. I suspect it's php5-fpm crashing because I get the dump file in the DocumentRoot folder. The file I get is named "core" and it is somewhere in the order of gigabytes in size.

Here is what I've already done to disable core dumps, without success:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/coredump.conf
```

and then rebooted. No dice.

```
echo '*               hard    core    0' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "fs.suid_dumpable = 0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

and then rebooted. Still no dice. I've NOT set kernel.suid_dumpable to 0, because I found it later but when I found it I also read that zero is its default. These settings should not make any difference anyway, because php5-fpm is not setuid. The same goes for Apache and mysql, just in case it's not php5-fpm crashing.

For the time being there is a script that looks for core dumps and deletes them. Crontab does the rest, but it is not the best solution.

How do I globally and unconditionally disable core dumps in Debian 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Michael Hampton's comment to the Froggiz' answer, I noticed that Debian seems to lack a coredump.conf manpage, so I've looked for it on the internet and found it. That manpage contains a lot of useful informations and I wonder why Debian ships without it (maybe Debian is shipping without the whole systemd-coredump thing?).

However from that manpage and the systemd-coredump manpage it seems that the core files I get do not come from systemd, because systemd puts them in /var/lib/systemd/coredump or in the journal depending on the Storage option, but never in the working directory of the crashed process. Moreover the systemd-coredump manpage (also missing in Debian) says that for the core dump functionality to work, you need to configure the kernel.core_pattern sysctl parameter to make the kernel actually hand the core dump to systemd-coredump.

I've then looked at Debian value for kernel.core_pattern: Debian comes with that parameter set to "core" by default, which happens to be exactly the name of the core dump files I get.

I now suppose that setting

```
kernel.core_pattern=|/bin/true
```

(or /bin/false for that matter) in sysctl.conf as per the core(5) manpage will solve the problem.

I'm going to evetually accept my answer in a few weeks if I notice the server stops creating core files. I'm sorry I can't accept Michael's comment as answer, but many thanks to him for pointing me in what I believe is the right direction.

EDIT: I've found [here](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/) a way to test the configuration without having to wait for a spontaneous crash and I confirm this is the correct answer.

Comment: Debian is kind of a bizarre distribution. They make strange and usually ill-considered changes to upstream packages all over the place. I can't recommend using it, or anything derived from it.

Comment: Points of view. I like it a lot, though I admit it is sometimes cryptic to understand.

Comment: This is not really a point of view. It's _important_. When a package doesn't behave as expected because the distribution changed how it behaves, you have a recipe for frustration at the very least.

Comment: There actually isn't any custom behavior here. It's just a default kernel configuration. The Debian systemd does behave as expected and so does the Debian kernel. It seems Debian does not use systemd-coredump at all, and I can only support such a choice, because a quick "systemd-coredump" google search brings up mostly people trying to disable it.

Comment: `systemd-coredump` is shipped in a different package that is not installed by default

Comment: @Bigon that was not the case in Debian 8 (Jessie), which is what my question targets

Comment: For what I can see, it was not even enabled in the version released in debian 8 (215-17). According to the change log it was disabled in version 43-1 and re-enabled (and put in a different package) in 227-3, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744964

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Disabling_application_crash_dumps_journaling

> Disabling application crash dumps journaling Edit the file
>   `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` by adding this line:  `Storage=none`
>
> and run:   `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the configuration.

Comment: How is that supposed to work, since I've already overridden any default coredump.conf with a symlink to /dev/null? I ask because each thing I try takes quite some time to test, so I prefer trying things only if I know they make sense.

Comment: @LucioCrusca Because getting rid of the file does not stop core dumps. The file's absence only tells systemd to use its built-in defaults (which _do_ generate core dumps). This was documented in the `coredump.conf` man page.